# Migrate wordpress to docker local to local

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a wordpress project I want to run it in docker container local to local

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - ./data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: test
       MYSQL_USER: root
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: 

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data:
```

This is what Ive done in powershell

```
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\mywordpress ##this is the path of my wordpress
```

Then `docker-compose up`

After that ive got this error

> ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: b"error while creating mount
>   source path '/host_mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/mywordpress/data': mkdir
>   /host_mnt/c: file exists"
>
> ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

This is the [site](https://joshmobley.net/writing/2017/04/09/easy-wordpress-migration-with-docker.html) Im following

Comment: There is something you are not telling. I took the file you gave and issued the command you gave on it, and I did not get your error.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh Im just following the tutorial. Maybe the path is wrong?

Comment: does your `data` folder exist in your directory where the docker-compose.yml is located?

Comment: @MazelTov yes it exist.

Comment: Are you working on Windows OS?

Comment: @Vivasaayi yes.